# Trouble with autoresizingMask and fixed margins

Tags: iphone, ios, autoresize, autoresizingmask

I'm trying to get this to work with code in a ViewController's view:

[image]

but I can't get it to work.

I've tried

```
-(void)loadView {
    UIView *contentView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.view = contentView;
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(5,5,0,100);
    button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [contentView addSubview:button];
}
```

but the width of the button is still the width of the superview...

I'm sure there's an easy explanation.

Thanks, everybody!

Antonio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-initWithFrame:` is the designated initializer for UIView. On the Mac side (NSView) I know strange things can happen when using `-init` instead of `-initWithFrame:`. Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, The result of the code above is the same if I -initWithFrame:. I can't get the button to grow but leaving 5 px margins on the sides...

Comment: Are you init'ing it with a frame width of 110? Also, you're putting your view into the content view (which may mess with its size on its own) before adding the appropriately-sized button to it. I'm not sure if that's what's actually happening, but it's probably best to construct your view hierarchy with known geometry before adding it to another, which might change it, triggering autosizing before your button has been added. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I had to init with a frame. Thanks for your help!

Comment: o_O Did you pass a zero rect when you tried -initWithFrame: the first time? (confused)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bothering with the `autoresizingMask` flag, I override `layoutSubviews` in custom `UIView` subclass:

```
- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [ContentView view];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 100);
}
```

where `ContentView` is defined as:

```
@interface ContentView : UIView {
    UIButton *button;
}

+ (id)view;

@end

@implementation ContentView {

+ (id)view {
    return [[self new] autorelease];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [self addSubview:button]; // Retains the button.
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    const CGFloat margin = 5;

    CGRect size = self.frame.size;
    button.frame = CGRectMake(margin, margin,
        size.width - 2 * margin,
        size.height - 2 * margin);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    UIView *contentView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
    self.view = contentView;
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(5,5,screenBounds.size.width - 10,100);
    [button setTitle:@"hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [contentView addSubview:button];
}
```